# Android Lollipop Set color of Shadow for Elevated Views

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Is it possible to change the **color of the shadow** created for views with an elevation. Currently it creates a shadow in grey, but in a dark themed app: black background the shadow does not show.

I was hoping to experiment with shadow color. I looked in the **themes_material.xml** file in dec/platforms/android-21..... and searched for shadow, it came up with 0 results.

Comment: No, this is not currently supported.